# Defining an half open interval on matlab

Tags: matlab

How would I go about setting my tspan vector for solutions to my ode between **(1,5]**? I've thought of just doing *>>tspan = [1:(any amount of steps):5]* but is that okay?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems ok, but 2 notes:

A. It should be `tspan=[1:(any size of step):5];`, not amount of steps. For amount of steps, you can write: `tspan=linspace(1,5,(any amount of steps));`

B. Those options are include '1'. If you want the interval (1,5], you shold add the size of step to '1' on each of the options. For example: `tspan=[1+(size of step) : (size of step) :5];`

Answer (score 0):

You can't *numerically* integrate over a (half) open interval. Numerical integration always operates at specific numeric points, i.e. not an interval anyway, but a finite set of numbers. What you specify with the `tspan` argument are the smallest and largest number in that set, and both therefore are included in it. You can put more numbers into `tspan` to explicitly request integration results at these points, too, but however you choose those this doesn't change the fact that you don't have an interval.

If the motivation of the question is that your equations have a singularity at 1, you might specify a start point that is slightly larger, e.g. `[1 + 1e-5, 5]`.